# How do I fix this Wi-Fi problem

Tags: wireless, laptop, asus, 32-bit

I already have downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" on an ASUS εee PC and I am not able to connect in a Wi-Fi network. Just like the Wi-Fi adapter is not working . I had Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and it worked fine . Is there something that I can do to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Download [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/522934) and [edit] your question to include a link to the pastebin output. This way people can have an overview.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Videonauth The script is perfect, but it looks like it is too hard for newbies to run it in most cases.

Comment: @Pilot6 well I'm not much familiar with WiFi, just thought o.k. its lacking information, and this is the most complete collection of information you guys can get AFAIK. Thus my comment. :)

Comment: The comment is good, but I found that many new users ignore such comments, because they do not know how to run the script and how to post the output. That's why I ask only for `lspci...`. If further information is needed I ask for something else.

Comment: @Pilot6 I made that script with the help of friends in 2012 and been upgrading it ever since,  we have made it as easy as possible with the one command being copied and pasted in the terminal to run the script and we tell them exactly where the file is created, the issue is when they do not have internet connection that makes it harder I agree there. But this script is all over the net and has been run thousands of times and it okay not to use it but please do not suggest it is to hard for a new person to use.  Thanks

Comment: @WildMan It is a very good script. But there are many cases when newbies fail to understand what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem right after the installation. One needs to download and install the corresponding drivers from "Software Updates > additional drivers" making use of cable connection. I would also `sudo apt-get update` before and after.